# React weird text animation that I can only recreate on my phone (not in inspect element's phone mode)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, tailwind-css

[image]

I have a component that I made that animates a single word, by cycling through a list of words and applied an animation to them.

Not only does it do this, it also dynamically sets the width of the word according to the width of the new word, and moves the adjacent words with an animation too. It's easier to look at the gif of it above.

The weird behavior is the "Draft Pick" keeps being put into 2 lines instead of 1, which results in it being weird looking.

here is where it's implemented

```js
<h1 className="text-white font-semibold text-[35px] lg:text-[50px] text-center title-shadow max-w-3xl">
        A Stats Gameplan <br/>
        to Help You Win More {" "} <br />
        <TextSwap
          strings={["ARAM", "Ranked", "Draft Pick", "Blind Pick"]}
          animationType="slideDown"
          className="text-winions-orange text-nowrap"
        />
        {" "}Games
        </h1>
```

here is the animation component

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const buildAnimationStyle = (type, durationMs, widthTransitionDurationMs) => ({
  display: "inline-block",
  animation: `${type} ${durationMs / 1000}s`,
  "animation-fill-mode": "forwards",
  transition: `width ${widthTransitionDurationMs / 1000}s ease`, // Convert milliseconds to seconds for CSS
});

// Additional style for the hidden span used to measure text width
const measureStyle = {
  visibility: "hidden",
  position: "absolute",
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  top: "-9999px",
  left: "-9999px",
};

export const TextSwap = ({
  strings,
  interval = 2000, // Default interval in milliseconds
  animationType = "fade",
  animationDuration = 2100, // Default duration in milliseconds
  className = "",
  widthTransitionDuration = 500, // Default width transition duration in milliseconds
}) => {
  const animationStyle = buildAnimationStyle(animationType, animationDuration, widthTransitionDuration);
  const [currString, setCurrString] = useState(strings[0]);
  const [containerWidth, setContainerWidth] = useState("auto");
  const measureRef = useRef(null);

  // Measure and update width based on the current string
  useEffect(() => {
    if (measureRef.current) {
      setContainerWidth(`${measureRef.current.offsetWidth}px`);
    }
    
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const currIndex = strings.indexOf(currString);
      const nextIndex = currIndex < strings.length - 1 ? currIndex + 1 : 0;
      setCurrString(strings[nextIndex]);
    }, interval);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [currString, strings, interval]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        key={currString}
        style={{ ...animationStyle, width: containerWidth }}
        className={className}
      >
        {currString}
      </div>
      {/* Invisible span to measure text width */}
      <span ref={measureRef} style={measureStyle}>
        {currString}
      </span>
    </>
  );
};
```

also what's weird, is that I **cannot** recreate this issue through my desktop browser (at any resolution), but when I push the changes to a testing environment (so that I can see it on my actual phone) the issue is there (??)

## I need help making the "Draft Pick" stay one line only!